# How to remove background to a select box in Chrome (on iOS)

Tags: html, css

This is how a select box is show on Chrome for iOS:

[image]

the background is not `#ffffff`, but there is a sort of opacity/shadow. How can I remove it? Tried background-color/image and so on, but nothing work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your css

`select{ background:none;}`